# How do I combine basic authentication and https?

Tags: apache, https, basic-authentication

I have setup a private website that needs to be accessible by only a few people via the internet. I'd like to setup a combination of basic authentication and https.

So far I have everything works ok if I directly type in `https://blah.com/location1`. However **what I need** is to have apache redirect `http://blah.com/location1` to `https://blah.com/location1` and THEN do basic authentication i.e I don't want basic authentication to be done before the redirection. At the moment this is what I have on my apache config.

```
WSGIScriptAlias /site /path/to/site/apache/site.wsgi

<Directory /path/to/site/apache>
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Location /site>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Site login"
    AuthUserFile /path/to/site/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

**Note:** I only need the authentication for `/site`. So I should be able to access `http://blah.com/site1`, `http://blah.com/site2` without needing authentication.

Comment: A question, why do you want basic authentication with https? With basic authentication the user credentials will be send in plain text.

Comment: That is why I need basic authentication to be done from `https` and not `http`. That way they are sent encrypted

Comment: i think u should just shift the `AuthType Basic ..` from http config to https, that's mean two separate configuration

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache .htaccess redirect to HTTPS before asking for user authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267102/apache-htaccess-redirect-to-https-before-asking-for-user-authentication)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the rewrite rules that "convert" HTTP requests into HTTPS requests is that they don't prevent the first request to be made over plain HTTP (as you get a redirect to the HTTPS URL).

What you could do is split your site into two virtual hosts: one for HTTP and one for HTTPS.

On the HTTP virtual host, implement the rewrite if you want, but forbid access to `<Location /location1>` in all cases (only do the rewrite).

On the HTTPS virtual host, configure `<Location /location1>` with basic authentication.

Comment: +1 This is the approach I use.  There's really no easy way to do this with one vhost.

Comment: I kind of inferred this from ajreal's comment . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I replied here [Apache 2.2 redirect to SSL *then* do auth (with solution < but is it crap?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458398/apache-2-2-redirect-to-ssl-then-do-auth-with-solution-but-is-it-crap/7822709#7822709), a solution which use `SSLRequireSSL`, and a `ErrorDocument 403` returning an html 403 error page containing a JavaScript which will reload the page to HTTPS ... the best solution I found without splitting the configuration file in two, one loaded by the `VirtualHost` on port HTTP, on the other on port HTTPS.